# Как сделать возможность выбора адреса с помощью гугл карт на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Мне нужно сделать сайт по доставке воды, для этого одно из полей это адрес доставки, так вот, я хочу сделать что бы можно было выбрать адрес с помощью какого-то виджета на сайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Яндекс карты](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapstools/#widget) - конструктор карт, возможно там можно что-то похожее сделать

[Автодополнение адреса в Input](https://habr.com/ru/post/214945/)